# Angular Favicon not getting saved correctly

Tags: angular, favicon

Favicon is not getting displayed on website.
I have checked favicon.ico on build files of Angular.
Favicon.ico does not have the image but it has something written in binary language.
It seems Favicon.ico is not saved correctly.
I deleted the file and pasted it again. But issue still persists.
Can someone please help on this?

Comment: You better had add some images of your query for people to understand quicker. Also you may want to clear browser cache once to reflect new icon.